# Can an Amazon EC2 Instance access another Instance by Private IP?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have two separate instances in my test scenario

1. Web Server Instance
2. Database Server Instance

So far the only way I can get from `1st` to `2nd` Instance is by having Elastic IP's configured and using the Public DNS (or IP) reference. I can limit unwanted access by configuring the Security Group for `2nd` to only take `Port 1433` traffic only from `1st`.

It seems like Instances within the same Amazon AWS zone should be able to talk to each other more efficiently than first going out and then coming back in.

Is there a way to go directly from `1st` to `2nd` instance using just the Private DNS (or IP)?

Comment: It may be intentional that Amazon has made it difficult to do something like that because the Private IP values can change if the Instance goes through a Stop / Start cycle. I just want to exhaust any chance that there is a good way to avoid outbound traffic charges and also have faster connection between Web & DB Instances.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you are using the Amazon Public DNS name, Amazon makes sure that all internal traffic gets routed internally only. So there is no problem in using the public DNS names. Have a look at [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/227682/whats-best-practice-for-communication-between-amazon-ec2-instances) and [this article](http://alestic.com/2009/06/ec2-elastic-ip-internal) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for that tip about how Amazon handles internal traffic even with Public DNS usage. With that knowledge, I added additional rule on the Security Group for Database Server Instance that allowed 1433 traffic from internal IP of Web Server Instance (same zone). Your article references have some suggestions of how to handle possibility of internal IP changing so I have more work to do on that end.

Comment: When configuring the security group, you can also grant access from another security group (and not only IPs). Make sure that your DB and web server are in different security groups. This makes it easier when relaunching instances and IPs change.

Comment: Mine are separate security groups already. So all I have to do is add the Web Server security group to the Database Server security group and I wont have to specify internal IP of Web Server? That sounds like a winner solution. I will try this out. Thanks